# How to capture a video of a certain tab using its ID

Tags: javascript, video-capture

I am trying to create an extension that views all the opened tabs with 2 buttons for each, start and stop. I want the start button to start the recording of the corresponding tab. I thought of using the `tab.id` like so:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture(
        {
          video: true,
          audio: true,
          videoConstraints: {
            mandatory: { chromeMediaSourceId: tabId },
          },
        },
        function (stream) {
           .........
```

but it just starts capturing the current tab. The reason why I am doing this is that I want to capture multiple tabs at the same time. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting `tabId` from? Otherwise have you tried using a fixed tabId or changed the tab-id while step-by-step debugging to see if the tab id would work?

Comment: what I am doing is actually first to loop on all the open tabs and save their ids and make the start button execute this function using its tab id, I am positive it is correct and nothing is wrong with it